# ViewPager height

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

I have got the following activity XML design:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        style="@style/leftdrawerStyle" />
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        style="@style/rightdrawerStyle" >
    </ExpandableListView>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/MyGmap"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/> 
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/follow_mode_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to divide the screen into two equal views:

1.one for the view pager.

2.other for map fragment.

**Note:** both drawers are not visible at the beginning till you swap left of right.Even if there is a way to do that programmatically, this will be perfect.

Comment: use layout weight for it.

Comment: I tried that but with no luck....!

Comment: layout weight will work if your parent layout is LinearLayout. so check the parent layout